# Use SVG-file as point symbol in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, svg, url

I want to make a map of traffic signs by using .svg image files of the traffic signs as point symbols. I put all the svg-files in the folder 'styles' in the data_dir of Geoserver (on my localhost). But for some reason, only grey squares appear, instead of the images. I am certain the files are placed in the correct folder. This is an excerpt of my SLD:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Traffic</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Name>trafficsign</Name>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>08970150-8c69-4c99-98d3-c2bd86035ac6</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>img</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>955544_aanzicht1.svg</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <ExternalGraphic>
                                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="955544_aanzicht1.svg" />
                                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                            </ExternalGraphic>
                            <Size>
                                <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
                            </Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>`

I must also say, that it did work when I uploaded a png-file to imgbb.com to create a URL, and copy/pasted the URL in the SLD. But it really seems like a lot of work to individually upload images and copy/pasting the URL in the SLD file (especially when dealing with close to a thousand different traffic signs).

Is there any reason why geoserver won't show my svg-files when using the relative path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a bunch of OS styles that work fine using the following syntax:

```
    <Rule>
      <Name>Triangulation Station - 1:1,000 to 1:5,001</Name>
      <ogc:Filter>       
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>featurecode</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>15408</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>5001</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ordnance_survey/triangulationStationSymbol-fc.svg"/>
            <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <Size>20</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

So yours should work.

Things that can go wrong include:

1. tomcat (or whoever is running GeoServer) can not read the file.
2. the style is in a workspace and you have placed the SVG file in the `style` directory instead of `workspace/style`.
3. Maybe GeoServer likes a directory ref in there - try `./955544_aanzicht1.svg`
4. your SVG is corrupt?

Note to save on the filtering you can use the file name directly in the SLD from the property:

```
<Graphic>
  <ExternalGraphic>
    <OnlineResource
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xlink:type="simple"
        xlink:href="osmmsymbols/${os_cat}.svg"/>
     <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
  </ExternalGraphic>
  <Size>50</Size>
  <Rotation>0</Rotation>
</Graphic>
```

Comment: Appreciate the tip on the filtering!